# jQuery <tr> link except button which opens Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I wanted to make my `<tr>'s` clickable / linked to a corresponding page. All rows have a button to delete the row aswell. Unfortunately when an user Clicks on the delete button it still links as the row is clicked. I added code so it would do that except button click.. so it could open the `bootstrap modal` for delete confirmation.

My script :

```
$('tr[data-href]:not(:button)').on("click", function() {
    document.location = $(this).data('href');
});
$('tr button[data-target]').on("click", function() {
    document.location = $(this).data('target');
});
```

HTML table with Blade foreach

```
                                  <tr style="cursor:pointer;!important;" data-href="/bugs/{{$project->id}}">
                                  <td>{{$project->created_at->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$project->projectnaam}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$project->liveurl}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$project->developmenturl}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$project->user->voornaam .' '. $project->user->tussenvoegsel .' '. $project->user->achternaam }}</td>
                                  <td>{!! substr($project->omschrijvingproject,0,90) !!}</td>
                                  <td class="text-right" >
                                  <a href="/projectmuteren/{{$project->id}}" class="">
                                       <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs wijzigKnop2" name="zoekProject" type="button" data-project="{{$project->projectnaam}}">
                                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                       </button>
                                  </a>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$project->id}}">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                  </button>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
```

Delete modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$proj->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Verwijder verzoek</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>Weet u zeker dat u het project : <strong>{{$proj->titel}}</strong> met alle gekoppelde data wilt verwijderen&hellip;</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Sluit</button>
                     <form method="POST" action="/verwijderProject/{{$proj->id}}" >
                     {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
                     {!! csrf_field() !!}
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-left">
                        {{--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>--}}
                        Verwijder project
                     </button>
                     </form>
                   </div>
                 </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
               </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
             </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Please reply with any solution on how to exclude the button click..

Comment: Can you provide MCVE replicating issue?

Comment: What is `MVCE replicating issue` ? @A.Wolff

Comment: Please, just search for it: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: will add table code and modal code in a few secs

Comment: Ya but server side code doesn't really help. Posting HTML markup has it appears in browser would be more relevant

Comment: The above code isn 't server side. Both are writen in the View.

Comment: If you inspect your table in browser, you'll get rendered/parsed HTML markup appearing in console. That's said, i'm really not sure to understand what you are expecting because even clicking on modal button, you are doing a redirection: `document.location = $(this).data('target');`. So your bootstrap modal hasn't really had time to be displayed. A bootstrap modal isn't true modal, it doesn't wait until confirmation to process any further code

Comment: Fixed it already =) refresh to see answer in OP

Comment: `change is .is(":button") to .is(':button')` No, it cannot just be it! `":button"` is strictly equivalent to `':button'` in js.

Comment: lol i tested it again and was because of a slow website hahahaha... deleteing now..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100654/discussion-between-stefano-groenland-and-a-wolff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as in bellow DEMO, hope it will help you a bit.

```js
$(".table").on("click", function (event) {
                var nodeName = event.target.nodeName;
               // alert(nodeName + "  Node Clicked");
                debugger
                if(nodeName == "BUTTON"){
                    alert($(event.target).data("btnid") + "  is the btn id")
                    //Do rest things 
                }
                if (nodeName == "TD") {
                    alert($(event.target).closest("tr").data("href") + "  is the href of row")
                    //DO rest things on row clicked
                }
            });

            $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                var btnID = button.data('btnid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
                // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
                var modal = $(this)             
                modal.find('.modal-body input#btnClickedID').val(btnID)
            })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr data-href="tr -href- 1">
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>john@example.com</td>
                    <td><button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-btnid="btn 1">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-href="tr -href- 2">
                    <td>Mary</td>
                    <td>Moe</td>
                    <td>mary@example.com</td>
                    <td><button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-btnid="btn 2">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-href="tr -href- 3">
                    <td>July</td>
                    <td>Dooley</td>
                    <td>july@example.com</td>
                    <td><button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-btnid="btn 3">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" id="btnClickedID"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        Try it Your
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent parent click event like below using `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('tr button[data-target]').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.location = $(this).data('target'); 
});
```

Comment: @StefanoGroenland Then i guess to open modal, event needs to bubble up. Then you should go with nikhil's answer instead

Comment: @A.Wolff I  don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @StefanoGroenland I'm not a bootstrap user but i guess bootrap modal is using some kind of delegated event (or bind click on any container). In these cases, click event need to propagate through the DOM.

Comment: the button has a data-target and the tr has a data-href if that's what you mean haha.

Comment: @StefanoGroenland I'm really not sure how this is handled. I'm sorry! If you are able to provide any link (jsFiddle?) where your specific issue can be checked, it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem faced is due to event bubbling.
You can update your click handler to following

```
   $('tr[data-href]').on("click", function() {
        if(!$(event.target).is(":button")) {
            document.location = $(this).data('href');
        }
    });
```

Comment: tried it problem still occurs. modal pops up for a sec and then still links to tr link.. @nikhil

Comment: @StefanoGroenland Are you sure it isn't becasue you are binding a click event to the button doing a redirection?

Comment: the button has a data-target which opens up the modal. and the row has an data-href.

Comment: @StefanoGroenland BUT you are binding click event to the button too, doing a redirection...

Comment: A redirection is to another page. This button opens a div which was hidden before clicking.. Would that count as a redirection??

Comment: @StefanoGroenland setting `document.location` is making a redirection. Again, your code doesnt wait for any modal result before redirecting.

Comment: Hmm do you know anything which will just trigger the click event without redirection?

Comment: @StefanoGroenland I'm sorry but i'm completly confused trying to understand what you are expecting here. Why would you need to redirect user? What is your expected behaviour? Why not provinding MCVE? Etc... You seem anyway confused too on what you are expecting. So soryy but i give up

Comment: @A.Wolff - i got a little busy. Thank you for resolving Stefano queries.