# table tr don't fire onclick or go to another page when i click the modal button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, modal-dialog, tr

I don't want to go to another page. If i clicked the button modal.
I will stay only to the page because the button modal is associated with the form in modal dialog.

But if i click to the tr itself. it will also allow me to redirect to another page.

```
<tr onclick="window.location='url';" style="cursor: pointer;">

<td>
     <p class="mb-1"><h5>Title</h5></p>
</td>

<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm apply" data-target="#div_jobApplicant" data-toggle="modal" data-modal-type="form" data-id="1">APPLY THIS JOB</button>
</td>

</tr>
```

Thank you for any help.

ALREADY RESOLVED-------

Reference:

[jQuery <tr> link except button which opens Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786106/jquery-tr-link-except-button-which-opens-bootstrap-modal)

```
$('tr[data-href]').on("click", function() {
    if(!$(event.target).is(":button")) {
        document.location = $(this).data('href');
    }
});
```

i just import this code. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you inspect the `button` for other function that could be conflicting with your `onclick` event. Maybe do a simple test by removing all the `button` attributes like `class` `data-target` ect... Maybe this answer might be of some help to find those other events.  [**Using Chrome, how to find to which events are bound to an element**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338193/using-chrome-how-to-find-to-which-events-are-bound-to-an-element#answer-7338319)

Comment: Thank you for the help.